# C++ - Value being lost

Tags: c++

I have a variable `int _width;` being set in a constructor of a class `Stage` as follows:

```
Stage::Stage():_width(33), _height(23)
{
...
}
```

And later I am using it in a pathfinding method, where I call:

`ex = fminf(_width - 1, current->x + 1);`

which is just setting an end X point for something else. The problem is I get a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)` error. When I try to log it out with `p _width` I get:

```
(lldb) p _width
error: Couldn't apply expression side effects : Couldn't dematerialize a result variable: couldn't read its memory
```

I'm not sure what's going on here. I'm not resetting the variable anywhere.

Comment: That suggests the `this` pointer is null, i.e. you've invoked a member function on an object which doesn't exist.

Comment: As in the `Stage` is getting deallocated?

Comment: no, as in it was never allocated in the first place (deallocating doesn't set pointers to null, it just makes the memory they point to no longer part of your program)

Comment: As in:  `Stage* s = nullptr;  s->foo();` That will compile, but has undefined behaviour. Typically inside the `foo()` member function the `this` pointer would be null, and trying to access any member variables of the object will cause the kind of access error you are seeing.

Comment: i'm creating the stage with `currentStage(new Stage())` right now. and just calling `currentStage->update(delta)` later in a loop. I'm not sure why this is behaving this way since there was no problem until i introduced the width variable, other variables were behaving correctly.

Comment: What is `currentStage`? A member of another object?

Comment: Yes, controlled by an `Engine` class right now, that updates everything, including the `Stage`. `currentStage` is just the currently loaded `Stage` to update.

Comment: I've figured out the problem, in the constructor of `Stage` i was calling a function that referred back to stage, which wasn't finished being constructed. Thank you for you help.

Comment: nit-pick that has nothing to do with your problem, you shouldn't start member names with _, those are technically reserved for variables that are only alive in the file (but I avoid them all together).

Comment: @IdeaHat - you mean private? it is private if that's what you mean.

Comment: @EvanWard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier sorry I got it wrong, "Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace"

Comment: Ah, yeah i'm not too proficient with C++, i'm used to _name being a declaration that the member is private/protected.